# How to perform regular expressions on a Speech Recognition transcript?

Tags: javascript, webkit, speech-recognition

Summary of my application:

1. **Input:** Have the user speak to the computer (ask the computer `"What is your name?"`) ✅
2. Perform a regular expression on the 'transcript' result (from `webkitSpeechRecognition`) ❌
3. **Output:** `console.log("My name is Harry Johnson")`. ❌

I'm trying to perform a regular expression on a speech recognition transcript, as follows:

```
var speechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition; 
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

var transcript;

recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {
     transcript = Array.from(e.results)
        .map(result => result[0])
        .map(result => result.transcript)
        .join('');
    console.log(transcript);
});

recognition.addEventListener('end',recognition.start);


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("speak_button").addEventListener('click', function() {
        recognition.start();
    });
});
```

The above works fine and I am able to console.log the transcript/speech from the user. The problem arises from the below code and I think it has something to do with the fact that the transcript has to be a string? I have tried converting the transcript to a string using String(transcript) and transcript.toString(), but I'm still not achieving my result: which is for the computer to console.log "My name is Harry Johnson".

```
function speakBackToMe() {

/*regular expression that will match words in the transcript */
    var person_name_regex = /what is your name|(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bfull\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\btell\b)(?=.*\bme\b)(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\bcan\b)(?=.*\btell\b)(?=.*\bme\b)(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\btell\b)(?=.*\bme\b)(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bfull\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\blet\b)(?=.*\bknow\b)(?=.*\bfull\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\bgrab\b)(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\bwhat\b)(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\bshare\b)(?=.*\bme\b)(?=.*\bfull\b)(?=.*\bname\b)|(?=.*\bwhat\b)(?=.*\byour\b)(?=.*\bfirst\b)(?=.*\band\b)(?=.*\blast\b)(?=.*\bname\b)/ig;
   
/*if regular expression matches all words, then function will be performed*/
    if (person_name_regex.test(transcript)) {
        console.log("My name is Harry Johnson");
        
}

}

speakBackToMe();
```

The regular expression is correct, the main problem is with the `transcript` variable. If anyone has any advice on why the `console.log("My name is Harry Johnson")` function is not being performed, it would be greatly appreciated if you could share that with me! :)

Thanks!

Comment: where do you get/store the `transcript` variable from? I don't see any reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me I just put the speakBackToMe(); line below console.log(transcript); within the result event listener block and it worked

```
recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {
     transcript = Array.from(e.results)
        .map(result => result[0])
        .map(result => result.transcript)
        .join('');
    console.log(transcript);
    speakBackToMe();
});
```